# Timer for camera feature in UWP

Tags: timer, camera, uwp, delay

I am currently development a UWP application and I have a camera feature in my program. However I wish to implement timers for the feature.

I wish to allow the user to select their preferred timing at the side, and click on the "Take a picture" button and on the camera screen it will show a timer and the event under the onclick for the "take a picture" button will be delayed according to the user's selection.

[image: camera page]

**Here is my code from .xaml:**

```
<CaptureElement Name="PreviewControl" Margin="566,77,166,50"/>
<Button x:Name="PhotoButton" Content="Take a picture!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="990,678,0,-91" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="PhotoButton_Click" Height="45" Width="313" Background="White" Foreground="Black"/>

//Timer buttons  
<Button x:Name="Timer_3sec" Content="3 seconds" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="66" Width="262" Background="White" Foreground="Black"/>
<Button x:Name="Timer_5sec" Content="5 seconds" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="66" Width="262" Background="White" Foreground="Black"/>
<Button x:Name="Timer_7sec" Content="7 seconds" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,337,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="66" Width="262" Background="White" Foreground="Black"/>
```

**Codes from xaml.cs:**

```
private async void PhotoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await TakePhotoAsync();
    }

private async Task TakePhotoAsync()
    {

        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        Debug.WriteLine("Taking photo...");
        await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);

        try
        {
            var file = await _captureFolder.CreateFileAsync("SimplePhoto.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            Debug.WriteLine("Photo taken! Saving to " + file.Path);

            var photoOrientation = CameraRotationHelper.ConvertSimpleOrientationToPhotoOrientation(_rotationHelper.GetCameraCaptureOrientation());

            await ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(stream, file, photoOrientation);
            Debug.WriteLine("Photo saved!");

            await Helpers.MessageDialogHelpers.ShowNoActionMessageBox("Your photo has been taken!", "");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // File I/O errors are reported as exceptions
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception when taking a photo: " + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a field in your code behind:

```
private int _seconds;
```

Set appropriate time in button handler:

```
private void Timer_3sec_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _seconds = 3;
}
```

Add the delay to photo button handler:

```
private async void PhotoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_seconds));
    await TakePhotoAsync();
}
```

This should be enough. If you will notice that your code behind is getting to complex because you are adding all the logic there try to read about MVVM.

Comment: On a side note, do you know if it is possible to display numbers (timer) on the camera screen? just so that the user know the countdown

Comment: Just add a TextBlock on top and change its Text propery.